# How do I find the odds for a voter in a problem involving different percentages?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The problem is as follows:

> In a certain community $30\%$ of the registered voters are members of
>   the Blue party, $45\%$ of the registered voters belong to the Green
>   party and the rest belong to the Orange party. At a recent election
>   for choosing the new mayor, $20\%$ of Blue party supporters went to
>   vote, $25\%$ of Green party supporters went to vote, and only $10\%$
>   supporters of Orange party went to vote. If a voter is selected
>   at random What is the probability that he has voted?

What I tried to do to solve this problem was to account the total percentage by considering the contribution for which each supporter gives to the total based on the turnout.

Therefore:

$\textrm{Blue party turnout:}$

$\frac{20}{100}\times\frac{30}{100}=\frac{6}{100}$

$\textrm{Green party turnout:}$

$\frac{25}{100}\times\frac{45}{100}=\frac{45}{400}$

$\textrm{Orange party turnout:}$

$\frac{10}{100}\times\frac{25}{100}=\frac{10}{400}$

Then I assumed that the total percentage should be the odds or probability to find a voter who has casted its vote.

$\frac{6}{100}+\frac{45}{400}+\frac{10}{400}=\frac{79}{400}$

By expressing the later in scientific notation I end up with $19.75\times10^{-2}$ or $0.1975$ so I concluded that this should be the answer.

But is it okay to assume this? The way how I proceeded to calculate the odds is correct?. What would be the best way to solve this problem without incurring into errors of perception?. If what I did was correct is there a conceptual or mathematical justification? I'd like someone could guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You did well.

More in probability terms:

Let $V$ denote the event that the selected person voted.

Let $B$ denote the event that the selected person belongs to Blue party.

Let $G$ denote the event that the selected person belongs to Green party.

Let $O$ denote the event that the selected person belongs to Orange party.

At first hand - because every person in the community will belong to exactly one of the $3$ mentioned parties - we have:

$$P(V)=P(V\cap B)+P(V\cap G)+P(V\cap O)$$

This can be rewritten as:
$$P(V)=P(V\mid B)P(B)+P(V\mid G)P(G)+P(V\mid O)P(O)=$$$$\frac{20}{100}\frac{30}{100}+\frac{25}{100}\frac{45}{100}+\frac{10}{100}\frac{25}{100}=\frac{79}{400}$$

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the mathematical notation that you have used maybe you want it to explain it to me. But is that vertical line between the brackets another way to say divide this number by this other number?. There is also another thing which I do not understand well. How do we calculate probability anyway?. I was kind of following my intuition and nothing else, but I'd like to know the conceptual basis for that. Can you include this? I'd like to learn exactly why the number is a probability for selecting someone at random.

Comment: $P(V\mid B)$ is a notation for a conditional probability: the probability that $V$ occurs under the condition that $B$ occurs. Probability calculation here is dividing the number of cases that correspond with the event by the total number of cases. Do you agree that - if e.g. an urn contains $4$ blue balls and $6$ non-blue balls - the probability of picking a blue ball is $4/10$? This because all balls have the same probability to be picked. This principle is applied here to find the probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 100000 voters. 30% of them, 30000, are "Blue party", 45% of them, 45000, are "Green party", and 25% of them, 25000, are "Orange party".
 20% of the "Blue party", .2(30000)= 6000, voted, 25% of the Green party, .25(4500)= 11250, voted, and 10% of the "Orange party", .10(25000)= 2500, voted.

That is a total of 6000+ 11250+ 2500= 19750 out of 100000 who voted.

The probability that a random person voted is 19750/100000= 0.19750.

Comment: Okay I understood your example and it does make sense but why did you choose to use $100000$ and not some number less?. Can you include in your answer a little bit of theoretical background of how probability is calculated? and why what I did or you had shown is consistent with it?

Comment: 100000 was chosen arbitrarily.  I just wanted a number large enough that I did not have to deal with fractions.